# Silverstripe administration tinyMCE 500 error prevents WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, tinymce, file-permissions, silverstripe

I have a basic Silverstripe CMS install on my web server however when I log into the administration I get a 500 error for this file:

```
Request         URL:http://sitename.com/framework/thirdparty/tinymce/tiny_mce_gzip.php?m=1426832960&js=1&plugins=table,emotions,paste,media,fullscreen,inlinepopups,advimagescale&themes=advanced&languages=en&diskcache=true&src=false
Request Method: GET
Status Code:    500 Internal Server Error
```

I have done some research and I am not sure what could be causing this or how to go about addressing the issue, I have tried changing the permissions of the file in question and the directories housing it but still get no resolve.

The error log states:

```
[Wed Sep 23 09:45:33 2015] [error] [client 000.00.000.000] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/frontend/public_html/newss/framework/thirdparty/tinymce/tiny_mce_gzip.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://sitename.com/admin/pages
```

TL;DR

```
The file is writeable by group
```

However when I check the permissions of this particular file I get:

```
0755
```

I have tried 0777 and 0555 and get the same result.

This setup with no changes works locally and I am not sure the differences.

Any help is appreciated. I don't know why but I feel like this is a PHP configuration issue but I'm not sure how to debug this either.

Comment: Check your error logs. 500 Internal Server Error is just a generic error code.

Comment: @Mike Updated with a little more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something like that once and disabled gzip useage for TinyMCE. Put this in your */mysite/_config/config.yml* (or any other yml there):

```
HtmlEditorField:
  use_gzip: false
```

Though it doesn't fix that bug you can work again.

See also:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3891

Comment: I will accept this answer as it solves the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with tiny_mce_gzip.php before. It was caused by **zlib.output_compression** isn't enable in my php.ini.